# Check time difference between method calls objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have this method:

```
- (void) receivedData {
}
```

This should run about every 50 to 100 milliseconds. Is there a way to check the time since the last time it was called and print the last time to an NSString?

Comment: Have a suitably persistent variable, either an NSDate or NSTimeInterval, assigned to the method.  On entry to the method do `[NSDate date]` to get the current time, compare to the saved value however you desire, then store the current time into the persistent variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface MyClass() {
    NSDate* receivedDataTimestamp;
    ....
}

...

-(void)receivedData {
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    if (receivedDataTimestamp != nil) {
        NSTimeInterval delta = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:receivedDataTimestamp];
        NSLog(@"%f seconds since recevedData was called last", delta);
    }
    receivedDataTimestamp = now;
    ....
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `%lf` for a double (which is what a NSTimeInterval is), and while it may not make a difference when using `printf`, it definitely would change things if using `scanf`.

Comment: @pauls -- thanks for fixing my flub -- I usually forget the `*` when I need it but when I don't need one they have a way of creeping in.